# Create index with a commentary

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, index, ssms

I would like to add some comments to my indices. So I added some additional information to the index creation script, expecting to see this comment again as soon as I open the script again. But it was gone.

Sample:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX test3
/* 
 Created on ...
 Reason: ... 
 Improvement: 95 - 99,8% ...
*/
ON [dbo].[T] 
(   
/* equal */
[ID], [Nr], [D], 
/* inequal */
[S], [OD])
INCLUDE 
([A], [C] )
```

After selection `SCRIPT => CREATE SCRIPT` in SSMS all comments are gone.

Does anyone know a solution to keep them alive?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no way to store text in the definition of an index.

You can use Extended Properties to store descriptive information, however it won't be automatically displayed when you "script" the object.

```
USE tempdb;

CREATE TABLE dbo.t1
(
    ID INT NOT NULL
);

CREATE INDEX IX_t1
ON dbo.t1(ID);

/*
    This will add a comment named "Comments" to the IX_t1 index
*/
EXEC sys.sp_addextendedproperty @name=N'Comments'
    , @value=N'This is a test index to store comments'
    , @level0type = N'SCHEMA'
    , @level0name = N'dbo'
    , @level1type = N'TABLE'
    , @level1name = N't1'
    , @level2type = N'INDEX'
    , @level2name = N'IX_t1';

/*
    This displays all comments associated with indices in the current database
*/
SELECT SchemaName = s.name
    , ObjectName = o.name
    , IndexName = i.name
    , PropertyName = xp.name
    , PropertyValue = xp.value
FROM sys.schemas s
    INNER JOIN sys.objects o ON s.schema_id = o.schema_id
    LEFT JOIN sys.indexes i ON o.object_id = i.object_id
CROSS APPLY sys.fn_listextendedproperty(NULL, N'SCHEMA', s.name, N'TABLE',
    o.name, CASE WHEN i.name IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE N'INDEX' END, i.name) xp
ORDER BY s.name
    , o.name
    , xp.name;
```

Results of above query:

[image]

```
/*
    This provides the ability to delete Extended Properties
*/
EXEC sys.sp_dropextendedproperty @name = N'Comments'
    , @level0type = N'SCHEMA'
    , @level0name = N'dbo'
    , @level1type = N'TABLE'
    , @level1name = N't1'
    , @level2type = N'INDEX'
    , @level2name = N'IX_t1';


/*
    Clean up my test bed
*/
DROP TABLE dbo.t1;
```

The best-practices solution for this problem is to store object definitions inside a version-control system.

Comment: ...or at least a data document of some kind (source control seems to be an alien concept in many db teams).

Comment: Max, yes this maybe an option, but not very comfortable in case I just want to add some comments quickly to the definition as possible for other object types in the schema. Sure, having source control will solve this bit there is none present at the moment. However I will accept your answer as the best and most complete answer.

Comment: I agree its frustrating that you cannot inline ad-hoc comments like you can with some other DDL statements.

Answer (score 3):

While it will not persist in the deployed version (as noted by Max Vernon - what happened to the bow tie?!) you can nevertheless keep this text available if you use a [Database Project](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh272686%28v=vs.103%29.aspx). Highly recommended because you can store a definition with notes as well as place the entire project under source control (which can store check-in/version comments also!) along with other benefits.

You can include the Index on the table definition with comments, or add it to a post deploy script which can do some fun things beyond storing comments! Like checking if the server has full text service installed, then determining if a catalog exists and creating it if not (some of my dev servers do not have that service running).

[image]

Comment: +1 - It's pretty much imperative to use *some kind* of source management system, even that only means keeping a copy of the DDL in .sql files on your filesystem.

Comment: [Your bow tie question has been answered....](http://meta.dba.stackexchange.com/questions/2371/what-on-earth-happened-to-max-vernons-bow-tie?cb=1)

Comment: I have experience with Database Projects and would love to introduce them, but unfortunately right now it's almost impossible to do so. So this does not solve my case, nevertheless your answer is quite useful.